# User to de-authorise app?

Tags: support, api-v2, authentication, oauth2

The API makes use of [OAuth](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) to allow queries such as [`/inbox/unread`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread). In the documentation however, I cannot seem to find a way for the user to control actively the authentication:

1. Is there a place for the user to have an overview of all apps he / she has authorised?
2. Can the user de-authorise an application? And so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user has any authorized applications, the `apps` tab appears on their profile pages.

From the page linked a user can see their authorized applications, and de-authorize any of them.

That link probably won't be conditionally displayed forever, but we haven't got anything to show in the "emtpy" case just yet.